# Spring batch job doesn't start from HTTP Rest call

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-batch

I am trying a make spring batch utility in which i will be reading files from a location and dump them into database.
I am calling batch jobs via 2 ways, one from scheduling and another from rest controller.

My batch config is below

```
  @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public SomeReader<Some> reader() {

        // some reader configuration
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeProcessor processor() {
        return new SomeProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeWriter<Person> writer() {
        // some config
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job someJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("someJob")
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Some, Some> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
     public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("ImportPoolThread-Utility");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

    }
```

my rest controller from where i call the job task

```
@RestController
public class JobInvokerController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @RequestMapping("/invokejob")
    public String handle() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        return "Task Batch job has been invoked.";
    }
}
```

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

my project start well. But job task of read/write only starts when i change my step name everytime i.e. step1 -->step2 or do the job name changes, this happens only when i call job launcher from rest end point.
Project starts but wont call the job task no matter how many times you hit the rest end point. But once you change step name or job name and restart the project, it start working and the task of read and write starts.
How to correct this, do i have to change job instance every time for calls from HTTP.
For that i also have provided taskExecutor with custom thread pool. referred this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html).

Don't know what i am doing wrong here, please assist.

Comment: That should not be the case, and it is not obvious from what you shared what could be the cause of this behaviour. So please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably starting a job which already completed, hence it won't start.
To start the same job again you can add a parameter with unique value -

Example:

`JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder(); jobParametersBuilder.addLong("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());`

Then pass this as parameter to job.